# Finding an upper bound for a probability of minimum by moment inequality

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, inequality, integral-inequality

Suppose we want to show that 
$$P[|S_j - S_i| \wedge |S_k - S_j| \ge \lambda] \le \frac{1}{\lambda}^{4\beta}C_{i,k}$$ for some $\lambda>0$, $\beta \ge 0$ and some $C_{i,k}$. 
Then how is this implied by the following moment inequality? 
$$E[|S_j - S_i|^{2\beta}|S_k-S_j|^{2\beta}]\le C_{i,k}$$

From Markov's inequality we have 
$P[||S_j - S_i| \wedge |S_k - S_j| \ge \lambda] \le \frac{E[|S_j-S_i| \wedge |S_k - S_j|]^{4\beta} }{\lambda^{4\beta}}$. But I don'tknow how to bound this by the expectation above. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the inclusion $$(|S_j - S_i| \wedge |S_k - S_j| \ge \lambda) = (|S_j - S_i| \ge \lambda) \cap (|S_k - S_j| \ge \lambda) \subset  (|S_j - S_i||S_k - S_j|  \geq \lambda^2)$$

Thus $$\begin{aligned}P(|S_j - S_i| \wedge |S_k - S_j| \ge \lambda) 
&\leq P(|S_j - S_i||S_k - S_j|  \geq \lambda^2) \\
&=P(|S_j - S_i|^{2\beta}|S_k - S_j|^{2\beta}\geq \lambda^{4\beta}) \\
&\leq \frac{C_{i,k}}{\lambda^{4\beta}} \end{aligned}$$